# Size of Xcode Project .ipa is WAY too big (1.6 GB)

Tags: ios, xcode, zip, size, ipa

I recently finished an app on Xcode and compressed it to a .zip file (or .ipa as I changed the ending later). However, I was shocked to see that the size of the .zip was 1.62 GB, which is incredibly large for an iOS app, and way too large to be accepted by iTunes Connect.

After looking over similar questions on Stack Overflow, I proceeded to remove all resources in my project to see if they were the cause of the problem. I took out any .PNG or .JPG image file, and also removed any .MP3 audio file. However, after compressing my app it was still at an absurd number - 1.56 GB!

I don't know what to do now, as I really need to submit this app but it is still way too big. I would appreciate any help on this issue. Thanks!

**Edit:** I had to create a completely new project in order to fix this issue, as I couldn't find what was making the size so big in the original project. I copied and pasted the storyboard, added all the image and audio files, and re-created the classes by copying and pasting the code.

Comment: Did you add any frameworks to your project? (Through cocoa pods or otherwise)

Comment: The only frameworks in my app are currently AVFoundation, AVKit, and MediaPlayer

Comment: What makes you think it won't be accepted by iTunes Connect? They limit the app size not the Xcode file size.

Comment: You do not create the IPA file by renaming the zip file that you created

Comment: Did u find any fix?

Comment: simply_me I ended up having to recreate the project. Didn't take too long though, I just copied and pasted each view controller on the storyboard and imported all of my assets